# re-naming data frame output given input parameter to class in python

Tags: python, class, pandas

I have managed to make my first class, containing two methods where on holds data and the other does a set of derivations on the input data, given fairly simple python code utilizing Pandas functionality. I call the class, and its adherent methods, with 4 parameters.

What I would like is for the output from the class, a Pandas data frame, to be named according to one of the input parameters - being an string object. This since the derivation is made on a single data column in the input data and it would be practical to name the output data frame to the same as the input parameter (i.e., data frame variable) for later use.

An crude example of the structure of the class (and of the code) is give below:

```
class tool_swoe_iv:
"docstring"

    def __init__(self,data_in):
        self.data_in = data_in

    def swoe_iv(self, param1, param2):
        "code that executes calculations"

        # output table which I would like to be re-named to param1 so it can be called later on. 
        woe_holder
```

When I call the class I would like the "woe_holder" data frame to have the same name as param1. Does my questions make sense? I come from a SAS background where the re-naming of the output data could easily have been done by a macro variable holding the name suffix.

Please note that im very new to the more formal parts of python coding involving classes and their development, honestly also to more standard python coding too.

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're misunderstanding how python class methods work. Here's what I think you believe your code will do:

```
#Create an instance of tool_swoe_iv
my_tool = tool_swoe_iv(5)

#Execute calculations
my_tool.swoe_iv(param1, param2)

#Now there exists a new dataframe called param1
```

What you're missing here is that python functions return *values*. For example:

```
def addition(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Now, if you want to have a variable that holds the result of an addition, you should assign it yourself, e.g.:

```
my_var = addition(1, 2)
```

Instead of doing it the way you're suggesting, with some function that looks like:

```
addition("myvar", 1, 2)
```

So using your original example, your code should look something like

```
 class tool_swoe_iv:
    "docstring"

    def __init__(self,data_in):
        self.data_in = data_in

    def swoe_iv(self, param2):
        "code that executes calculations"

        # output table which I would like to be re-named to param1 so it can be called later on. 
        return dataframe

my_tool = tool_swoe_iv(5)
param1 = my_tool.swoe_iv(param2)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer! I get the intuition, and it make sense to me seeing it like this with how you assign the class into the param1. I can then reuse that in the rest of the code and just re-assign the class to all the other variables I want to execute the calculations for.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly modify dictionary of variables by calling `locals()` and `globals()` function. For example, `a = 1` is equal to `locals()['a'] = 1`.

So, you can use those functions to accomplish your idea:

```
globals()[param1] = woe_holder
```

However, this is not suggested, because you will assign it to a global name instead of local name. (If you use `locals()`, it will disappear when your function returns, because it will be a local variable of *your* function.) You'd better just return `woe_holder` to the caller and let the caller decide what name to assign to. For example, call `my_tool.swoe_iv` like that:

```
param1 = my_tool.swoe_iv(param2)
```

(In this case param1 can't be a object. Don't enclose it with quotation marks.)

This is more readable.